# Cannot load jersey resource classes to JBoss 7

Tags: xml, jersey, jboss7.x

- Jersey - 1.16
- JBoss - 7.1.2 Final

With the above, I cannot load resource classes to `JBoss` and it complains about the below error.

> ERROR [[/]] Servlet  threw load() exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: Resource configuration class, biz.bsite.direct.spring.mobile.AddressbookResource, is not a super class of class javax.ws.rs.core.Application 
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:741) 
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678) 
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203) 
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374) 
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)

My resource class looks like as below.

> @Path("addressbook") 
>   public class AddressbookResource {

Web.xml looks like:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyMobile</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>biz.bsite.direct.spring.mobile.AddressbookResource</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Could someone please help me to solve this? Tried to use the package scanning but it also not working with JBoss 7.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct approach is to use app server agnostic JAX-RS deployment model as explained [here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e188). All you need is, extend [javax.ws.rs.core.Application](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) in your JAX-RS web application. Here is an example.

```
package com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.resources;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(HelloWorldResource.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

Then, you need to put this in your web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.resources.MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.resources.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.resources.MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In addition to deploying as an JAX-RS Application, you need to disable resteasy scanning your resources and providers.

I have put together a simple Jersey JBoss EAR sample in Github [here](https://github.com/aruld/jersey-jboss-ear).